# Switch and if statement returns the first case condition regardless if it is true or not

Tags: php

I am working on a , project which i have configured to serves multiple pages from one index.php file using a switch statement like this:

```
switch(isset($_GET['q']{
    case 'page':
        require 'link_to_page.php';
        break;
    case 'login':
        require = 'link_to_login.php';
        break;
    default:
        require = 'link_to_404.php';
        break;
}
```

As time goes by and more pages are added, i decided to move it to a `selectPage()` function which i now called and assigned to a variable `$page` and required it in my index.php file to make things simpler like this:

```
myFunctions.php

selectPage()
{
    switch(isset($_GET['q']{
        case 'page':
            $output = 'link_to_page.php';
            break;
        case 'login':
            $output = 'link_to_login.php';
            break;
        default:
            $output = 'link_to_404.php';
            break;
        return $output;
    }
}
```

My index.php looks like this:

```
require 'myFunctions.php';

$page = selectPage();

require $page;
```

Now the problem here is, regardless of which case is `true` `case page:` or `case 'login':`, `$output` returned is always equal to the first line of `case` condition checked, for example when `case page:` is the first line of `case` statement and `$_GET['q'] == 'login'`, `case page:` `$output` value is returned, when i swapped the `case 'login':` with `case page:` for it to be the first condition checked, `case 'login':` `$output` value which is  now the first line of condition is returned even if `$_GET['q'] == 'page'`.

i have also tried it with an `if(statement)` and the same thing happened.
How do i fix this, is there something am doing wrong?

Comment: Please at least show your actual code, or valid code that shows the problem. The stuff you've given us isn't even valid so how are we meant to know whether this is a syntax error or logical?

Comment: [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) will return only true or false. you may need to check `switch ($_GET['q'])`

Comment: a) you have a parse error. you have to close parentheses you've opened. b) isset($_GET['q']) can **never** be page, login, or anything other except `true` or `false` - because that's what isset returns.

Comment: `switch(isset($_GET['q']{` what?

Comment: you should write `return $output` outside of switch

Comment: return is outside the switch statement and the parenthesis are properly closed, this was just a type error.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error your Switch statement.

Right SYNTAX :

```
switch (n) {
    case label1:
        code to be executed if n=label1;
        break;
    case label2:
        code to be executed if n=label2;
        break;
    case label3:
        code to be executed if n=label3;
        break;
    ...
    default:
        code to be executed if n is different from all labels;
}
```

So, `myFunctions.php` Page

```
function selectPage()
{
    $page = isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : null;
    switch ($page) {
        case "page":
            return 'link_to_page.php';
            break;
        case "login":
            return "link_to_login.php";
            break;
        default:
           return "link_to_404.php";
    }
}
```

`index.php` page

```
require 'myFunctions.php';
$page = selectPage();
require $page;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 switch($_GET['q']){
    ....
 }
```

Comment: You need to explain **why** OP's current logic didn't work.

Comment: Still facing the same problem.

Comment: You are comparing the result of isset($_GET['q']) which is always true whether q ='login' or other. So it try to check true == 'page' which in this case would return true, so everytime it goes to the first case of the switch.

Comment: @tsommie : update your question with exact code you are trying ? by fixing all syntax errors(`brackets for switch`)

Answer (score 0):

You try to check `$_GET['q']` but really you check `isset($_GET['q'])`, so when PHP gets `true` it tries to compare values you give in `case` statement with `true`. And as your value are not empty or `false` values, that  condition is true, and code under it will execute.

Comment: Although offers a solution, you should directly say the solution.

Comment: I use isset to avoid breaking the code if 'q' is not set. but i have tried $_GET['q'] and the same thing happened.